# PHP The time in seconds before the date specified in format

Tags: php, jquery, datetime

I use countdown timer and have this code

```
<script>
$(function(){

    var time = '<?php echo $tojs; ?>';
    var clock = $('#clockMain').FlipClock({
        clockFace: 'HourlyCounter',
        //clockFace: 'TwentyFourHourClock',
        autoStart: false,
        language: 'ru',
        callbacks: {
            stop: function() {
                $('.message').html('Акция завершена!')
            }
        }
    });

    clock.setTime(5400);
    clock.setCountdown(true);
    clock.start();


});
</script>
```

In admin panel (Wordpress) i check date in format 30-01-2015
How i can get the difference from time() to time from my date in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the time in seconds with strtotime

```
$delta = strtotime("30-01-2015") - time();
```

Flipclock takes seconds as its input. You should be able to take $delta as parameter and inject it into Flipclock. I believe that should work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(<?php echo intval($delta);?>, {
        countdown: true
    });
</script>
```

Comment: That actually returns a time difference in seconds, not milliseconds.

Comment: ok, my time - time() = 25540
after / 60 / 60 ? this is my seconds?

Comment: @ValeriyDonika - edited the answer. Arjan is right, it comes in seconds... My Oops!

Comment: 2,  days in timer i see 7 hours :(

Comment: there is my $delta value = 23237

Comment: I am not familiar with flipclock myself, but I can only guess that it is a setting in there. Try `clockFace: 'DailyCounter'`. Further more you will probably have to see if you need to adjust the timezone. That is a bit of a different issue. First to get you going on this flipclock....

Comment: 23237 seconds is about 7 hours. Where do you get 2 days?

Comment: in the begining i have this:
$time =  30-01-2015 after i do 
$time = strtotime($time);
first value is 1422576000
after : i do 
$delta = $time - time();
and get 21795

Comment: Yes... and that difference is for your countdown. I am confused. The flipclock example shows a countdown with 3600 seconds. Filling in the 21795 should work just fine and give you a countdown of about 6 hours. That is what you want in your question above.

Comment: i think i have problem with times on my server

Comment: i have other problem. in the end, my counter have this look http://c2n.me/3bsgpcl
although he had to stop